# set the viewing specification of "google map" to a particular area only

Tags: android, google-maps

Is these is possible to set the google map viewing of a particular area only and denied other's.

Real scenerio

Actually I like to set the google map of a park, able to view any part of the park but not outside the park map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but it's not simple.  You would need to create a transparent View on top of the MapView, and use that to receive touch events.  These you would use to pan/zoom the map around indirectly, and thereby only allow the panning to occur within the limits that you want.

Comment: well I'm not sure what you're asking for -- how to create a transparent overlay?  You would simply make the overlay view a sibling to the MapView, inside a FrameLayout, after the MapView. How to track and respond to touch events?  There is a good tutorial on creating a drag/zoom interface here:  http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=content;siu-container. 

or something else?